# Kubernetes Pod Cannot Resolve Service by Name

Tags: python, kubernetes, microservices

I am new to kubernetes and I am having trouble with my deployment. I have a local k8s cluster (minikube) running 2 Pods (rabbitMQ and a python microservice that needs to connect to rabbitMQ). I have created a Service for RMQ but I cannot get the microservice to be able to connect using the Service by Name. If I use the Service Endpoint IP in place of the name just to test that RMQ is deployed correctly it works fine. I'm also aware the it's best practice to use Helm Charts to deploy rabbitMQ but since I'm learning k8s, I was wanting to get this working first before migrating to Helm. I should also note that this is all working when run with docker-compose, I'm wanting to migrate from compose to k8s.

rabbitMQ deployment yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq3
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rabbitmq3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rabbitmq3
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rabbitmq
        image: rabbitmq:3.11.10-management-alpine
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 5672
            name: amqp
          - containerPort: 15672
            name: discovery
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq3
  name: rmqserver-ui
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: discovery
      port: 15672
      targetPort: 15672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq3
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: rabbitmq3
  name: rmqserver
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - name: amqp
      port: 5672
      targetPort: 5672
  selector:
    app: rabbitmq3
```

The python microservice uses Pika to connect to rabbitMQ via the DNS name (`rmqserver` as defined in the Service name yaml above). This code is running in a separate Pod

```
# self._rmqusername and self._rmqpassword are guest/guest
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(self._rmqusername, self._rmqpassword)
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=rmqserver, credentials=credentials))
```

When I deploy the microservice to k8s the Pod logs throw:

```
2023-03-03 19:54:26,572 [ERROR] Address resolution failed: gaierror(-3, 'Try again')
2023-03-03 19:54:26,573 [ERROR] getaddrinfo failed: gaierror(-3, 'Try again').
2023-03-03 19:54:26,573 [ERROR] AMQP connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - gaierror(-3, 'Try again'); first exception - None.
2023-03-03 19:54:26,573 [ERROR] AMQPConnectionWorkflow - reporting failure: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - gaierror(-3, 'Try again'); first exception - None
2023-03-03 19:54:26,574 [ERROR] Connection workflow failed: AMQPConnectionWorkflowFailed: 1 exceptions in all; last exception - gaierror(-3, 'Try again'); first exception - None
2023-03-03 19:54:26,574 [ERROR] Error in _create_connection().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 451, in _create_connection
    raise self._reap_last_connection_workflow_error(error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pika/adapters/utils/selector_ioloop_adapter.py", line 565, in _resolve
    result = socket.getaddrinfo(self._host, self._port, self._family,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Try again
```

If I set the host equal to the Service Endpoint IP, there is no exception and it will connect. So this leads me to believe a problem with the DNS name lookup and that I'm missing a step / configuration.

Comment: Have you tried `rmqserver.default.svc` to connect to the service? Here `default` is the namespace of `rmqserver`

Comment: Yes, same error with `rmqserver` and `rmqserver.default.svc` and `rmqserver.default.svc.cluster.local`. Still works with Service Host Endpoint IP. My namespace is currently `default` for all deployments.

Comment: Ok,  when you say works with service host `ep` , what it means? The pod ip?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem -- if I deploy your manifests without modification and then start up a Python pod, I can successfully connect to the rabbitmq service using the hostname `rmqserver`. If you're able to reproduce this consistently, can you update the question to include a deployment manifest for a Python application that reproduces the problem? Is there any chance that your application is simply trying to connect before rabbitmq is ready to accept connections?

Comment: @larsks that's really interesting to hear and thank you for the investigation...the only other variable I can think of is my docker images are hosted on a private repository that requires a VPN connection. Do you think because I'm on a VPN when running this it's interfering with the Name lookup? It's repeatable every time for me and I am verifying 
 RMQ is running before I try to connect...the VPN makes me wonder, I'll try off the VPN and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting back with an update that fixed the problem. I deleted a worker node that I had created with `$ minikube node add` when I was first learning to set up minikube.

```
$ minikube status


minikube
type: Control Plane
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured


minikube-m02
type: Worker
host: Running
kubelet: Running
```

After deleting `minikube-m02` and reapplying the RMQ Deployment and python service Pod, it connected just fine. I'm not sure why the Node caused the problem though.